# Capture HTTPS request to nonexistent server with FiddlerCore

Tags: https, fiddler, fiddlercore

I am trying to send a response to an HTTPS request, using FiddlerCore.
I need things to work like this: I put some fake URL in browser, like `https://my_url_that_doesnt_exist.com/`, then I intercept this request with FiddlerCore and respond to it with my data.  But I only see a CONNECT and the host URL. I know this is because of HTTPS and Fiddler being a proxy. But is there a way to get the real full URL and be able to respond to HTTPS request, using FiddlerCore?

Also I use this code to create a root certificate if it's missing:

```js
if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.rootCertExists())
{
    if (!Fiddler.CertMaker.createRootCert())
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not create a certificate.");
    }
}
```

also, I use these startup settings:

```js
FiddlerCoreStartupFlags fcsf = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default | FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL|FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.AllowRemoteClients;
```

and `CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;`

This HTTPS request is not visible in Fiddler itself. I mean when I try some non-existent URL to which I'd like my app to respond with some custom content. It's also HTTP, not HTTPS, and Fiddler itself contains the following in response:

```
[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "my_url_that_doesnt_exist.com" failed. The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

But if I use some existing HTTPS URL, like google plus or anything like that, I can see the HTTPS and all the request details.

So the question follows: How can I intercept HTTPS request to a non-existent URL and serve my content instead?

I can provide any additional details if needed.

Also `makecert.exe` is in the same folder where all my binaries are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that HTTPS traffic flows through a CONNECT tunnel, and by default that secure traffic won't be sent if creating the CONNECT tunnel to the target server doesn't first succeed. Of course, if that target server doesn't exist, you end up with a DNS error in creating the tunnel, so the secure requests are never sent.

The workaround is to tell Fiddler to tell the client that the CONNECT tunnel was created, without even trying to contact the server. Do so by adding this inside the `BeforeRequest` handler:

```
if (oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT"))
{
  oSession.oFlags["x-replywithtunnel"] = "GenerateTunnel";
  return;
}
```